# I am getting the error foreach line in tcl error sys wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"

Tags: tcl

variable buffer = "nohup tcpdump -ni  eth0 -s0  2>&1

Actually i am searching a digit in the variable my code is

```
foreach line [split $buffer "\n"]
{     
if {[regexp {\[\d\]\s+(\d+)} $line junk pid]}
break 
}  
if {[info exists $pid]} 
{puts "PID of nohup is $pid}
```

I am getting error as: wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command" while executing "foreach line $lines{" what is the issue with the foreach command please help me for the correct code

Comment: I am getting error as: 
wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"
    while executing
"foreach line $lines{"
what is the issue with the foreach command please help

Comment: Open brace should be placed in same line for the command body, unless line continuation (i.e. backslash  character) used. Apply this rule to both `foreach` and `if` commands in your code.

Comment: You mean to say
foreach line [split $buffer "\n"]{     
if {[regexp {\[\d\]\s+(\d+)} $line junk pid]}
break }  
if {[info exists $pid]} {
puts "PID of nohup is $pid}

But it doesnot work.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh it is working now thank you very much